# Node.js Proxy for out going calls

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a local mockup server for an iOS app. I have a running deployed server like url: "`http://some-running-server.com/`" I would like to be able to use a local `http://127.0.0.1/getuser` using node.js.

In the app i would user `http://some-running-server.com/getuser`

I have seen "Charles" application can do this. Maybe someone have done this in Nodes, so you a able to test agents a local mockup using only node.js?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your browser to use `127.0.0.1` as a proxy (network settings), then run your code on localhost (127.0.0.1) and respond to the request. The url can stay the same as the original one. You can use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to forward the request to the original server, if you want to.

Comment: I have edited my question. Will node-http-proxy still do the trick? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the url to your hosts file. If your on OSX or Linux you can find it in etc/hosts. On windows the file is at %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\ just map the url to your local IP

```
 127.0.0.1 localhost
 # mapping some-running-server to localhost for development
 127.0.0.1 http://some-running-server.com
```

Just remember to remove the entry when you go to production!